# fb:request-form showing blank page

Tags: facebook, xfbml, fbrequest-form

This is my code

```
<fb:serverFbml style="width: 760px;">
<script type="text/fbml">
<fb:fbml>
<fb:request-form
action="http://apps.facebook.com/MyAPP/invite.php"
target="_top"
method="POST"
invite="true"
type="Invite Form"
content="<fb:req-choice url='http://www.example.com/folder/index.php' label='Accept' />"
>
```

If i have action="http://www.example.com/folder/invite.php" then it posts array of friends invited in invite.php page, but it takes user outside facebook interface.
If i have action="http://apps.facebook.com/MyAPP/invite.php" then it stays in facebook interface but loads a blank page for invite.php.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path rather than the full URL?  EG if you're already in your app at `http://apps.facebook.com/MyAPP/`, try just `invite.php` as the URL

Comment: well tried that but then i get error which says "serverfbml 'action' attribute must be within the application's connect url" :(

Comment: Damn I searched and tried several things but :( No use. Any one got any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if I have `action=apps.facebook.com/MyAPP/invite.php` then `<fb:request-form>` doesn't post the ids array to the page. So I tried `action="MyDomain.com/folder/invite.php";` and it gave me the ids in and array which I stored in a session and then have this page redirect the user back to `apps.facebook.com/MyAPP`. There I checked the number array processed it the way I wanted. Not sure this is best way to go about it though.

Comment: Please use the preview pane to make sure your posts are formatted correctly. About 75% of your post was completely cut off because the `<fb:request-form>` tag was not formatted as code.